# Weather radar loop on Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to implement a looping radar animation on a google map.  This site: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/  provides radar images from the current time to 60 minutes ago.

Currently, I am loading these images and using a timer to add/remove each image to the map.  This technically works, but the result is very choppy.  There is noticable time where there is no radar image visable on the map.  Lowering the timeout, only worsens the effect because the radar image does not have enough time to load before it is removed.

Are there any techniques to smooth out the animation?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Code

```
  var map;
  var imageArray = [];
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5, -95.5),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    //Load Images and add them to imageArray
    tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD',
        isPng: true,
    });
    imageArray.push(tileNEX);

    tileNEX5 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m05m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD5',
        isPng: true,
    });
    imageArray.push(tileNEX5);

    tileNEX10 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m10m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD10',
        isPng: true,
        optimized: false
    });
    imageArray.push(tileNEX10);

    tileNEX15 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m15m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD15',
        isPng: true,
    });
    imageArray.push(tileNEX15);

    tileNEX20 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m20m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.60,
        name : 'NEXRAD20',
        isPng: true,
    });
    imageArray.push(tileNEX20);


   animateRadar(imageArray);


  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  function animateRadar(images) {
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(images[0]);//Add first image
    var index = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
        map.overlayMapTypes.pop();//Remove previous image
        index++;
        if(index >= images.length){
            index = 0;
        }

        map.overlayMapTypes.push(images[index]);//Add new image
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In hopes that this helps someone else, below is how I ended up solving the problem.  Instead of adding/removing overlay images, I simply altered the opacity.  This gave me a much smoother animation.  The below example will cycle through the last 30 minutes of radar images.

```
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5, -95.5),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    //Load Images and add them to imageArray
    tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX);

    tileNEX5 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m05m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD5',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX5);

    tileNEX10 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m10m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD10',
        isPng: true,
        optimized: false
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX10);

    tileNEX15 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m15m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD15',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX15);

    tileNEX20 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m20m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD20',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX20);

    tileNEX25 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m25m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD25',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX25);

    tileNEX30 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m30m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity:0.00,
        name : 'NEXRAD30',
        isPng: true,
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX30);

    animateRadar();


  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  function animateRadar() {
    var index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;

    window.setInterval(function(){

        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.00);

        index--;
        if(index < 0){
            index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;
        }
        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.60);
    }, 400);
  }
```

}

Comment: This works perfectly! Will it auto-update as the days go by, or do you have to put in a refresh interval on the page?

Comment: The weather tiles would need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

question you know if this site mesonet has some sort of smooth layer at smaller level if zoom is 12

unless i can loop the animation with

http://radblast.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/radar/WUNIDS_composite?maxlat=34.96496076302826&maxlon=-89.51954101562501&minlat=29.38958076527275&minlon=-98.30860351562501&type=00Q&frame=0&num=7&delay=25&width=800&height=600&png=0&smooth=1&min=0&noclutter=1&rainsnow=1&nodebug=0&theext=.gif&merge=elev&reproj.automerc=1&timelabel=1&timelabel.x=200&timelabel.y=12&brand=wundermap&rand=4564

Comment: See http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/ for all they have to offer.  I don't believe they have a smoothed radar however.

Comment: Ahhhhh cool ya know i actually used your method quite awesome. its been working well (when the zoom is at 12 it does get pixelated) but i guess anything at that level is pixels. i might actually try 
tileNEX35
tileNEX40
http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m40m/

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, and sorry for necro'ing this, but is there anyway to have other overlays (say any of their GOES images) be displayed without actually "animating" them?

Basically I have code that looks like (and then I'm controlling the show/hide with the selectors with the jQuery):

```
    overlayMaps = [{
    //NEXRAD
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0r-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.60,
    name: 'NEXRAD',
    isPng: true
}, {
    //MRMS Hybrid-Scan Reflectivity Composite
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/q2-hsr-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.60,
    name: 'GOES Water Vapor',
    isPng: true
}, {
    //GOESVIS
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-vis-1km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.60,
    name: 'GOES Visible',
    isPng: true
}, {
    //GOESIR
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-ir-4km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.60,
    name: 'GOES Infrared',
    isPng: true
}, {
    //GOESWaterVapor
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-wv-4km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.9,
    name: 'GOES Water Vapor',
    isPng: true
}];

    $('.overlay_layer').click(function() {
        var layerID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if (map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() > 0) {
                map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(layerID, null);
            }
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var overlayMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType(overlayMaps[layerID]);
            map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(layerID, overlayMap);
        }
    });

for (i = 0; i < overlayMaps.length; i++) {
    var overlayMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType(overlayMaps[00]);
    map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(00, overlayMap);
    //map.overlayMapTypes.push(null);
}
```

The problem comes from the fact, I can't seem to find a way to only choose certain tiles to actually animate and not every overlay in map.overlayMapTypes.getLength()